# how to improve the performance of this recursion code in mathematica

Tags: recursion, wolfram-mathematica

```
Clear[r, re, p, pmax, delta, imagesize, delta]
ClearSystemCache[]
re[0, r_] := Sqrt[8/Pi]*((1 - r)/r)^(1/4)*1; 
re[1, r_] := Sqrt[8/Pi]*((1 - r)/r)^(1/4)*-1*2*(1 - 2*r); 
re[p_, r_] := re[p, r] = Sqrt[8/Pi]*((1 - r)/r)^(1/4)*(-1)^p*(re[1, r]*re[p - 1, r] - re[p - 2, r]); 
imagesize = 32; 
pmax = 10; 
delta = 2/imagesize; 
Table[r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]; re[pmax, r], {x, -1 + delta/2, 1 - delta/2, delta}, {y, 1 - delta/2, -1 + delta/2, -delta}];
```

this code is to calculate the distance r from each pixel to point(0,0), then evaluate the radial polynomial as below:

[image]

for accuracy, I will use the recursion version:

[image].

When the `imagesize` and `pmax` increase, the time will become unacceptable. So, I would ask if we can use compile of other methods to speed up, like for `imagesize` is 256 and `pmax` is 120, the time will be about 10 seconds.
In my code, I also use the memoization to store the value during the evaluation which I will use in the future.

Comment: You might try this `Simplify[RSolve[{re[0] == c, re[1] == c*-1*2*(1 - 2*r), re[p] == c*(-1)^p*((c*-1*2*(1 - 2*r))*re[p - 1] - re[p - 2])}, re[p], p]] /. c -> Sqrt[8/Pi]*((1 - r)/r)^(1/4)` There are lots of common subexpressions in that result which you could calculate once, store in a variable and the replace all those subexpressions with simple variables. If you do all that carefully and simplify the result you might end up with a reasonable sized expression with a few variables and no recursion.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to see if it helps

Comment: You might try this `sol = re[p] /. (Simplify[RSolve[{re[0] == c, re[1] == c*-1*2*(1 - 2*r), re[p] == c*(-1)^p*((c*-1*2*(1 - 2*r))*re[p - 1] - re[p - 2])}, re[p], p]] /. c -> Sqrt[8/Pi]*((1 - r)/r)^(1/4))[[1]];` and after that `imagesize = 32; pmax = 10; 
delta = 2/imagesize; t=Table[Chop[(sol + 0.) /. {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], p -> pmax}], {x, -1 + delta/2, 1 - delta/2, delta}, {y, 1 - delta/2, -1 + delta/2, -delta}];` The `Simplify` takes a fair amount of time, but it is reducing an expression with 50000 terms down to 10000 terms. I am not certain all this is correct. Please test this carefully

Comment: Please see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185933/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-this-recursion-code-in-mathematica?answertab=votes#tab-top